# Get attribution from Adjust SDK in Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I creating an app with Cordova and I need to use Adjust SDK for attribution Google Ads campaigns.
Also I need to put attribution data in variables.
Here is code example:

```
var adjustConfig = new AdjustConfig("token", AdjustConfig.EnvironmentSandbox);
      adjustConfig.setAttributionCallbackListener(function(attribution) {
        // Printing all attribution properties.
        console.log("Attribution changed!");
        console.log("trackerToken: " + attribution.trackerToken);
        console.log("trackerName: " + attribution.trackerName);
        console.log("network: " + attribution.network);
        console.log("campaign: " + attribution.campaign);
        console.log("adgroup: " + attribution.adgroup);
        console.log("creative: " + attribution.creative);
        console.log("clickLabel: " + attribution.clickLabel);
        console.log("adid: " + attribution.adid);
      });
      Adjust.create(adjustConfig);
```

Code above returns test data to console, but attribution data, for example `attribution.campaign` isn't available from outside of `setAttributionCallbackListener`.
I tried to log `adjustConfig` but it returns `null` for all parameters:

```
{
   "appToken":"token",
   "environment":"sandbox",
   "delayStart":0,
   "logLevel":null,
   "referrer":null,
   "userAgent":null,
   "isDeviceKnown":null,
   "defaultTracker":null,
   "externalDeviceId":null,
   "urlStrategy":null,
   "sendInBackground":null,
   "shouldLaunchDeeplink":null,
   "eventBufferingEnabled":null,
   "attributionCallback":null,
   "eventTrackingFailedCallback":null,
   "sessionTrackingSucceededCallback":null,
   "sessionTrackingFailedCallback":null,
   "deferredDeeplinkCallback":null,
   "sdkPrefix":"cordova4.23.0",
   "secretId":null,
   "info1":null,
   "info2":null,
   "info3":null,
   "info4":null,
   "processName":null,
   "readMobileEquipmentIdentity":null,
   "allowiAdInfoReading":null,
   "allowIdfaReading":null,
   "handleSkAdNetwork":null
}
```